# Select button in selemium c#

Tags: c#, selenium

How can I select the last button in this code? the only thing that changes is the value.

button class="btn btn-link btn-star" data-value="26">/button>

button class="btn btn-link btn-star" data-value="27">/button>

Comment: @JeffC Please don't spam all the questions with _...See: How do I do X?..._ comment as specifically this question have a accepted answer and additionally received multiple answers. I would suggest you to take some time to understand the _usecases_  OP refers to.

Comment: @DebanjanB It doesn't matter whether it has an answer or not, it's not a well formed question. Maybe you should read [ask] again so you know what a good question looks like? The better question is why aren't you asking OP to clean up their question?

Comment: @JeffC None of the StackOverflow best practices mattered to you in 6 years and nor would be in future. Keep spamming, you're of course, welcome to ignore the community guidelines.

Comment: @DebanjanB OK... this question has malformed/incomplete HTML, the HTML is not formatted, there is no code nor code attempts, and the description isn't exactly clear. You are saying there's nothing to fix/improve here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following Xpath to find the last element.

```
//button[@class='btn btn-link btn-star'][last()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try css selector
button.btn.btn-link.btn-star:last